# Does roo library work with Ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using ruby 2.0 to parse a xlsx. I have an instruction like that on my program `co = Excelx.new("Teste.xlsx")`. I didn't get this error on this line: `uninitialized constant Excelx (NameError)`. It seems to be right, since I've followed the roo documentation. Is roo supported on ruby 2.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does work with ruby 2.0, try appending the `Roo` module. For instance:

```
require 'roo'

co = Roo::Excelx.new("Teste.xlsx")
```

I tested that with `ruby-2.0.0-p0`

Comment: Using Roo::Excelx.new("Teste.xlsx") instead of just Excelx.new("Teste.xlsx") worked for me as you mentioned @fmendez.

Comment: I had issues with rails 3.2.6 as well. But changed Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore) to Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore).,